# JavaScript showing the alert either I choose the right path to upload the file

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Currently, I'm causing the JavaScript error either I choose the right path to upload the file. It was working really well in IE11 but no idea why it's not working anymore when we migrated to Microsoft Edge because IE11 is gonna shut down soon. I will provide codes as much as possible to fix the error.**Updated: I found a problem. That is when I choose file to upload in Edge, it doesn't show the path of the drive. (Example, R//:example.csv). It just show the folder's name so JavaScript alert keep showing because of Path of the file is not shown. But in IE11, it shows the full path with folder's name. Is there anyway to fix it?**

```
echo "<TR>";
            echo "<TD colSpan='2' align='center' id='uploadCell'>";
                echo "<label id='note'>Please upload csv file only</label><br>";
                echo "<input type='file' name='uploadFile' id='uploadFile'></input>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='file_src' id='file_src'></input>"; 
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='category' id='category'></input>"; 
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='folder' id='folder'></input>"; 
            echo "</TD>";
        echo "</TR>";
```

Below is the javascript. I will provide full JavaScript codes fore better result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
        var tstr = $('#tester').val();
        var file = $('#uploadFile').val();
        var category = "";
        var folder = "";

        document.getElementById("file_src").value= file; //added Su 24Jun2020


        //added Su 09Jul2021
        if(document.getElementById("st").checked == true){
            category = document.getElementById("st").value;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("secure").checked == true){
            category = document.getElementById("secure").value;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("tram").checked == true){
            folder = document.getElementById("tram").value;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("rel").checked == true){
            folder = document.getElementById("rel").value;
        }

        document.getElementById("category").value= category; 
        document.getElementById("folder").value= folder; 
        //end

        if(tstr == ''){
            alert('Please select tester entity.');
            e.preventDefault();                 
        } 
        //added Su 09Jul2021
        else  if(category == ''){
            alert('Please select category.');
            e.preventDefault();                 
        } 
        else  if(folder == ''){
            alert('Please select folder.');
            e.preventDefault();                 
        }
        //end
        else  if(file == ''){
            alert('Please upload a csv file.');
            e.preventDefault();                 
        } 
        /*else if(pathOK < 0 && envi == "eng"){
            alert('Please upload a csv file from release drive.');
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }*/
        else {
            var type =  file.split('.').pop();
            if(type != 'csv'){
                alert('Please upload CSV type of file only.');
                e.preventDefault();                 
            }
        }
    }); 
    
</script>
```

Another one is uploadDB.php file. In that file, the Alert codes were written so I will provide.

```
$orig_path = isset($_POST["file_src"])? $_POST["file_src"] : ""; 
$drive = substr($orig_path,0,1);
if($drive != "R"){

echo "<script Language=\"Javascript\">";
        echo "alert('Please use R:\\\ drive to map release folder for CSV file upload.'); ";
        echo "window.history.back();";
    echo "</script>";
    return false;
```

}

The problem is either I choose csv file from R drive path, it still showing Please use R drive to map release folder for CSV file upload. Is there anyway to fix? It was working well in IE but no working in Edge.

Comment: Microsoft have an Internet Explorer Mode in their Edge browser. See my answer update for the link. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Security**

The problem being encountered is web standards -  In some cases IE11 continued to support non standard behavior introduced in older versions so that customers could continue to run existing web pages without the need of a rewrite. In this case the issue is of disclosing the local file system path of files selected by an `input` element of `type="file".

Standards based browser treat supplying structural details of a user's file system to be a security risk and don't include information about the path of files selected by `browse` or dropped onto page using a drag and drop operation.

The Microsoft Internet Explorer series of browsers, however, included and continued to include the file system path of files being uploaded by the user, allowing PHP on the server to determine which drive a file was uploaded from using these lines:

```
$orig_path = isset($_POST["file_src"])? $_POST["file_src"] : ""; 
$drive = substr($orig_path,0,1);
```

**Conclusion**

Edge, like other Chromium based browsers, does not include file path in information provided for files being uploaded. You will no longer be able to get the file path of a file being uploaded from a `file` object in Edge.

I am not aware of any way to bypass security on the front end and assume a design change to user interaction will be required.

**Internet Explorer Mode in Edge (update)**

While Microsoft is retiring IE11 as of June 15 (next week), some of its functionality can be accessed in Edge by triggering [Internet Explorer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode). It requires configuration and testing which I am not in a position to conduct or experiment with.

Unless you disagree, I suggest investigating this option before others to see if it solves the immediate problem.

Comment: I found a problem. That is when I choose file to upload in Edge, it doesn't show the path of the drive. (Example, R//:example.csv). It just show the folder's name so JavaScript alert keep showing because of Path of the file is not shown. But in IE11, it shows the full path with folder's name. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: No there is no way to "fix it" such that you can send the file path of a file being uploaded from the front end using standard browser functionality. Some change to upload procedure or user interaction will be needed. What and how changes are made depends on the environment - is it an intranet, is the `R` drive a network drive, are user PCs on a network so the server can access their file systems, can users be persuaded to put complete a release field in the csv file etc. Using the path to check for release is no longer an option.

Comment: yes, it is an intranet website and R drive is a network drive. Also, is there anyway to change the method?

Comment: My first thought was to check on the server if a file of the same name and last modified date was already in the networked R drive and, if necessary, compare the uploaded file content with that of the file already in `R:`. Note that browsers are known to round or truncate date-modified values to an integer number of milliseconds for forensic forgery detection, so comparing date-modified values between uploaded and files on R may be inexact.

Comment: You might check out [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) for questions related to this issue - I am not a webmaster  :)